Why doesn't LazyVStack release memory when scrolling
I have a `PhotosPicker` that selects an image. Then, upon pressing the "Save" button, I save it in `FileManager` and store its path in `CoreData`. When I need to retrieve them, I use a `LazyVStack` that fetches the paths from `CoreData` for the images currently visible on the screen and displays them based on those paths. However, when an image goes off-screen during scrolling, it should free up memory for the new images appearing, but it doesn't. The memory usage grows, space isn't freed, and the app starts to slow down. How can I ensure that memory is freed when scrolling through the array?
//MARK: -CoreData manager
class CoreDataManager: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    
    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: -Save
    func saveImage(filePath: String) {
        let photo = Photo(context: container.viewContext)
            photo.filePath = filePath
                
            saveContext()
    }

    //MARK: -Fetch
    func fetchImages() -> [Photo]  {
      
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Photo> = Photo.fetchRequest()
        
        do {
            return try container.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to fetch images: \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: -Save context
    func saveContext() {
        let conetext = self.container.viewContext
        if conetext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try self.container.viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

//MARK: -Content view
struct ContentView: View {
 
    @StateObject var vm = ContentViewModel()
    
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem? = nil
    @State private var selectedImageData: Data? = nil
    
    @State var arrayPhoto:[Photo] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
           
            PhotoPicker()
            
            if let data = selectedImageData, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .clipped()
                    .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 20))
            }
            
            Button("Save") {
                vm.saveImage(data: selectedImageData)
                arrayPhoto = CoreDataManager.shared.fetchImages()
                selectedImageData = nil
            }
            
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(arrayPhoto) { imageEntity in
                        if let filePath = imageEntity.filePath {
                            Image(uiImage: vm.getImages(filePath))
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
                                .clipped()
                                .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 20))
                                
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            getPhotos()
            print(arrayPhoto.count)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: -PhotosPicker
    @ViewBuilder
    func PhotoPicker() -> some View {
        PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItem, matching: .images, photoLibrary: .shared()) {
            Text("Select a photo")
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedItem) { newItem in
            Task {
                if let data = try? await newItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                    
                    selectedImageData  = data
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: -Get photos
    func getPhotos() {
        arrayPhoto = CoreDataManager.shared.fetchImages()
    }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
 
    // MARK: -Save image to FileManager
    func saveImage(data: Data?) {
        guard let imageData = data else { return }
        let fileName = UUID().uuidString + ".png"
        let fileURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        
        do {
            try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
            saveFilePathToCoreData(filePath: fileName)
            
            print(fileURL.path(percentEncoded: false))
        } catch {
            print("Error saving image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: -Save file path to CoreData
    func saveFilePathToCoreData(filePath: String) {
        CoreDataManager.shared.saveImage(filePath: filePath)
    }
  
    // MARK: -Get Documents Directory
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    }

    
    // MARK: -Get images
    func getImages(_ path: String) -> UIImage {
        let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent(path)
        
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            
            guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) else {return UIImage()}
            
//            uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
            
            return uiImage

        } catch  {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return UIImage()
    }
}


You can create an ImageView struct for image loading asynchronously. Also lazy load the images only when it is necessary. By doing so memory management will become efficient.
Refer the below refactored code more reference:


    class CoreDataManager: ObservableObject {
        static let shared = CoreDataManager()
        let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
        init() {
            container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataModel")
            container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        func saveImage(filePath: String) {
            let photo = Photo(context: container.viewContext)
            photo.filePath = filePath
            saveContext()
        }
    
        func fetchImages() -> [Photo]  {
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Photo> = Photo.fetchRequest()
            do {
                return try container.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            } catch {
                print("Failed to fetch images: \(error)")
                return []
            }
        }
    
        func saveContext() {
            let context = self.container.viewContext
            if context.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try self.container.viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

    struct ContentView: View {
        @StateObject var vm = ContentViewModel()
        @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem? = nil
        @State private var selectedImageData: Data? = nil
        @State var arrayPhoto: [Photo] = []
    
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                PhotoPicker()
                
                if let data = selectedImageData, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        .clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                }
                
                Button("Save") {
                    vm.saveImage(data: selectedImageData)
                    arrayPhoto = CoreDataManager.shared.fetchImages()
                    selectedImageData = nil
                }
                
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(arrayPhoto) { imageEntity in
                            if let filePath = imageEntity.filePath {
                                ImageView(filePath: filePath, viewModel: vm)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
                                    .clipped()
                                    .cornerRadius(20)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                getPhotos()
                print(arrayPhoto.count)
            }
        }
    
        @ViewBuilder
        func PhotoPicker() -> some View {
            PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItem, matching: .images, photoLibrary: .shared()) {
                Text("Select a photo")
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedItem) { newItem in
                Task {
                    if let data = try? await newItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                        selectedImageData = data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        func getPhotos() {
            arrayPhoto = CoreDataManager.shared.fetchImages()
        }
    }
    
 
    struct ImageView: View {
        let filePath: String
        @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel
        @State private var image: UIImage? = nil
    
        var body: some View {
            Group {
                if let image = image {
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                } else {
                    ProgressView()
                        .onAppear {
                            loadImage()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    
        private func loadImage() {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let uiImage = viewModel.getImages(filePath)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.image = uiImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
        func saveImage(data: Data?) {
            guard let imageData = data else { return }
            let fileName = UUID().uuidString + ".png"
            let fileURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    
            do {
                try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
                saveFilePathToCoreData(filePath: fileName)
                print(fileURL.path(percentEncoded: false))
            } catch {
                print("Error saving image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    
        func saveFilePathToCoreData(filePath: String) {
            CoreDataManager.shared.saveImage(filePath: filePath)
        }
    
        func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
            return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        }
    
        func getImages(_ path: String) -> UIImage {
            let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent(path)
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) else { return UIImage() }
                return uiImage
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            return UIImage()
        }
    }




Don't work. Memory growing

LazyVStack doesn't destroy the views it scrolls off-screen, it retains them, and hence leads to growing memory usage.
I'm not sure there's any formal documentation regarding this, and if so it's well hidden, but several investigations of exactly what you are experiencing suggest it.
Can you use List to avoid this issue?
